# Javascript Map#getKeys() not found

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascript project, and I want to create a Map containing a string id and an object. I'm setting values with the usual `Map.set(id, obj)`. I am then trying to loop through the keys using `for (var key of map.keys())`, however I keep getting an error that "getKeys() is not a function or its return type is not iterable". I'm following the example on MDN, but it just doesn't seem to pick up on `getKeys()`. Is there something I'm missing?

```
  loopServers() {
    this.list = [];
    if (servers != null) {
      for (var key of servers.getKeys()) {
        this.list.push(key);
      }
      this.array = new ARList(width / 2, 100, 200, 25, this.list, 20, 30, 100, 200, 50, 170, 123, 195);
    }
  }
```

In this code, `servers` is my Map variable that I am pulling from my NodeJS server.

```
  socket.on("get", function(data) {
    servers = data;
  });
```

```
var servers = new Map;

  setInterval(serv, 50);

  function serv() {
    io.sockets.emit('get', servers);
  }
```

Comment: Try putting a `console.log(servers);` right below `servers = data;`, and then let me know what it prints out. My guess is that it's getting converted to a plain object.

Comment: I did that and it printed out
```
{}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's really a Map, and not an object, you just do `.keys()`, not `.getKeys()`.  Also, rather than looping you can just use `Array.from`:

```
loopServers() {
    this.list = [];
    if (servers != null) {
      this.list = Array.from(server.keys());
      this.array = new ARList(width / 2, 100, 200, 25, this.list, 20, 30, 100, 200, 50, 170, 123, 195);
    }
}
```

If it's an object, you could convert it back by doing:

```
servers = new Map(Object.entries(servers));
```

Comment: Using `Array.from` I still get the not a function error both for `.keys()` and `.getKeys()`
Converting it back to a map I get an empty Map

Comment: Sounds like you can't send a map over the socket, maybe do: `io.sockets.emit('get', servers.entries().reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({...acc, [key]: value,{}))`

Comment: I get a parsing error at `value,{}` for the `{}`. Should I put something else there?

Comment: sorry try this: `Array.from(servers.entries()).reduce((main, [key, value]) => ({...main, [key]: value}), {})`

Comment: That fixed the issue of sending the map from the server to the client. My second issue is when I try and set values. I set the keys and values, but when I get the map it is empty.

```
      var id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
      emitToServer('create', id, new Server(id, new Game()));
```

```
    socket.on('create', function(id, server) {
      console.log("Creating server " + id);
      servers.set(id, server);
      console.log(servers);
    });
```
I get a Map with a bunch of ids and undefined obj on the server, but the client gets an empty map.